# CSS/JS not working in firefox , works on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

It seems that this code works well in most browsers, except Firefox.
I tried the moz abreviations in css and js tweaks and it didn't help, maybe there's a property that Mozzila Firefox does not support or .. ? Help.

//   CSS:

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

body * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    text-align: center;
}
header > h1{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888, 1px 1px 1px #EEE;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: white;
}
header > h2{
    font-size: 10pt;    
    color: black;
}
header > nav > ul{
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:"horizontal";
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 2;
}
header > nav > ul > li{

    -webkit-box-flex: 1;    
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}

#carousel{
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    background: black;  
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #777;
}

#carousel > div{ 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    padding: 0;
}

#carousel > div > ul{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

#carousel ul li{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
}


//    JS important part:

    function Element(id, width, height, params){

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.rotateX = params.rotate.x;
        this.rotateY = params.rotate.y;
        this.rotateZ = params.rotate.z;

        this.margin = 10;

        this.translateX = params.translate.x;
        this.translateY = params.translate.y;
        this.translateZ = -(params.translate.z + this.margin);

        var dom = document.createElement("li");
        dom.style.display = "-moz-box";
        dom.style.mozBoxOrient = "vertical";

        dom.style.width = this.width+"px";
        dom.style.height = this.height+"px";
        dom.style.padding = "10px";
        dom.style.background = "00ff00";
        dom.style.opacity = "0.8";

        //use flex
        var imgObj = getImageUrl();
        var img = document.createElement("div");
        img.style.mozBoxFlex = "10";
        img.style.background = "url("+imgObj.url+") no-repeat white";
        img.style.mozBackgroundSize = "100% 100%"; 

        var title = document.createElement("div");
        title.style.mozBoxFlex = "1";
        title.style.textAlign = "center";
        title.style.paddingTop = "5px";
        title.textContent = imgObj.title;
        title.style.background = "#2e3231";
        title.style.color = "white";
        dom.appendChild(img);
        dom.appendChild(title);

        // dom.style.opacity = "0.8";
        dom.style.mozUserSelect = "none";
        dom.id = id;
        dom.addEventListener("click", elementClickHandler);
        dom.style.mozTransform  = "rotateY("+this.rotateY+"rad) translateY("+this.translateY+"px) translateZ("+this.translateZ+"px)";



        this.getElement = function(){
            return dom;
        }

        this.update = function(){
            dom.style.mozTransform  = "rotateY("+this.rotateY+"rad) translateY("+this.translateY+"px) translateZ("+this.translateZ+"px)";
        }
```

Comment: none of it works? Or is there something specific not working?

Comment: Your javascript is in CSS file :)

Comment: please narrow down... "doesn't work" is too general... do you have a JS error on the console? something in the css is wrong?

Comment: `-webkit` prefixed styles don't work in FF. You should add at least a non-prefixed version of properties too, and check, if FF needs `-moz` prefix for some properties. And the same in JS, for example only Chrome knows what is `dom.style.webkitTransform`...

Comment: The transformer does not work , nor the images. The styling fails too because everything is stacked insted of in their right place.

Answer (score 2):

You are using experimental features which have not yet been adopted as standards. You can tell this because of the vendor prefixes that allow you try these features out. For Chrome, the prefix is:

`-webkit-`

Yuo have included this prefix, so Chrome is happy. However, Firefox's prefix for these features is:

`-moz-`

So, if you want broader support, you need to include all the possible variants:

```
-webkit-box-orient: "horizontal";
-moz-box-orient: "horizontal";
-o-box-orient: "horizontal"; //For opera
-ms-box-orient: "horizontal"; //For IE < 10
box-orient: "horizontal"; //For the future
```

You should look at leveraging Modernizr, which can normalize some of this in your javascript code:

http://modernizr.com/

As an example, here is how I would normalize the `animation-duration` property:

```
 this.animationDurationNames = {
        'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationDuration',
        'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationDuration',
        'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationDuration',
        'animation' : 'animationDuration'
    };

 var animationDurationName = this.animationDurationNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];
```

Now I can simply reference `animationDurationName` when I need to work with the `animation-duration` property without having to worry about all the prefixes.

Comment: As I specified before , I added to the css/js above all the -moz- attributes and still it does not work . That's why I tend to think that there might be some mozzila attribute that does not exist. (from those listed with webkit above)

Comment: Update your code above with your edits.

Comment: Updated. I didn't use modernizr yet. Can you possibly expand on the matter with an example using the code above ? I understand webkitTransform is not recognized in FF , but how about mozTransform ? Is there another way ?

Comment: Firefox uses the non-prefixed property `transform`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility Can you set up a jsfiddle? That would help immensely.

Comment: The transformer works now .. I tried before it before like that with Transform without the moz prefix , it didn't work because of the uppercase T (I didn't see that little error being focused on smth else) .. The problem with the styling/images is still there.